# Serializing payload to be sent through serial port

Tags: c#, serialization, serial-port, packet

I'm trying to send this byte array: 0x7E 0x02 0x40 0x01 0x00 0x06 0xDA 0x7E
through a serial port but it has to be serialized first. I'm not sure how to go about that. I also have to deserialized the data coming in from the serial port. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Use a networkstream and then deseialize the stream results.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.networkstream?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 1):

The protocol data unit on a serial port is bytes; there is no need to serialise them. You can simply write the bytes to the serial port, and you'll get those bytes coming out of the other end of the cable.

How serial ports behave can be a bit tricky. Unixes like Linux often think of them as "text" devices and so start interpreting the byte stream coming in as if you were typing it on a keyboard (so a ^H 0x08 is backspace and is interpreted as such). So you have to be careful to configure the serial port to be a raw, binary interface.

If the port is text only, well that's where binary encoding like base64 come in, it's effectively a text serialisation for bytes.

You also need to get configuration and wiring right; using hardware flow control and got the corresponding wires connected?

And then there's message demarcation. And depending on what flow control you've configured there's nothing to stop the sending end if the receiving end is not running, so you can have a start up order problem.

Basically serial ports are a damned nuisance to use, and protocols like xmodem and ymodem were developed to make transfers reliable. if you want a serial port to exchange datagrams (well, files) as reliably and as certainly as, say, a tcp network socket you need to use something like xmodem or ymodem  between your application and the serial port. The problem is that these are ancient tech, but there appears to be some implementations.